# Получение ID процесса

Tags: c++, qt, процесс

Как исправить данную проблему, использую QT C++. Нужно получить PID запущенного приложения

```
DWORD GetProcessID(const char* processName)
{
    if (!processName) return 0;

    DWORD id = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap) {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
        if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32)) {
            while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32)) {
                if (strcmp(processName, pe32.szExeFile) == 0) {
                    id = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }
    return id;
}
```

[image: QT PROJECT]

Comment: И код, и ошибка должны быть текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: проверяйте, обновил

Answer (score 1):

Да просто раз уж работаете с Unicode и широкими символами, то не используйте `strcmp`, каковая работает только для "узких".

[`wcscmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscmp) вам в помощь...

Да, и вместо `const char* processName` используйте широкую строку.